# How to override default CSS in modern GWT applications?

Tags: css, gwt, cssresource, clientbundle

From the following page: [Developer's Guide - CSS Style](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html)

it is made clear that in modern `GWT` apps there's two ways to declare `css` styles:

Using a CssResource contained within a ClientBundle.
Using an inline  element in a UiBinder template.

How do you use either of these two methods to override the `GWT` default styles such as `gwt-Button`, `gwt-TextBox` etc?

I know it's still possible to use a css style sheet that you reference from either the html page or the .gwt.xml file. However, I'd like to avoid this since these methods are now deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an `@external` @-rule to disable obfuscation for the given CSS class names: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes
You can, for instance, put the following in any `CssResource` stylesheet:

```
@external .gwt-*;
```

But IMO, the *best practice* is to instead `addStyleName` or `setStyleName` (or in UiBinder `addStyleNames="…"` or `styleName="…"` respectively) on widgets. And if you want to customize a theme, copy it first as your own theme and tweak your own copy (rather than overriding styles using the CSS *cascade*). As an added benefit, you'll have lighter stylesheets, so they'll be faster to download for your users, and *“faster is better”*.

As a side note, UiBinder generates an implicit `ClientBundle`, where each `<ui:style>` element generates an implicit `CssResource` (and automatically calls `ensureInjected()` on it); so there's no much difference between `<ui:style>` and a `CssResource`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I can't get this to work.
I've commented out all the themes from the .gwt.xml file and added the following entry to my .css file:
@external .gwt-Textbox {
 color: red;
}
Then I'm unsure whether I need to add a method to my CssResourceClass or not. If I add the following lines:
@ClassName("gwt-Textbox")
String gwtTextbox();
I get an error when launching the app.
If I don't add it the TextBox in this case is not affected by the css.

Comment: No. Use `@external gwt-TextBox;` on one line (don't forget the semi-colon) to disable obfuscation for that CSS class name, and _then_ use `.gwt-TextBox` anywhere in your stylesheet, e.g. `.gwt-TextBox { color: red; }`. You don't need a method on your `CssResource` if you use the default class name for the widget (what would you use that method for?)